# How to check until file exist

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there any way to check until file exists in VBA.

what I am trying to do is, making vba call asynch.

Now after I run

```
wshShell.Run """" & SFilename & """" & s
```

I want to check until file exists like this

```
Wait until fso.fileexists("file")
  Msgbox "file is now available"
End wait!!!
```

is there any way in vba?

I am using word vba.

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win003.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Do

    If fso.FileExists("file") Then

        Exit Do
    End If

    DoEvents 'Prevents Excel from being unresponsive
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01") 'wait for one second
Loop

MsgBox "file available", vbOKOnly, ""
```

Although this is surely not the best method

---

Instead of using Application.Wait, you can use sleep:

```
Sleep 1000 '1 Second
```

but you need to add this to your code to be able to use it:

```
#If VBA7 Then  
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems  
#Else  
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds as Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems  
#End If
```

Comment: Thanks. "poor uncle is better than no uncle"

Comment: I excel it works. Word however show error at .wait `method or data not found`

Comment: Where did my thanks went? I already thanked on this comment. Any way. Thanks. It's working in test. Let me check it for real.

Comment: Making sleep 10 gives nice non-freezing word session. How?

Answer (score 1):

You need a timeout to avoid an endless loop. This function returns true if it found the file and false if timeout was reached.

```
Option Explicit

Const timeoutSeconds As Long = 128

Private localFSO As Object
Public Function FSO() As Object
    If localFSO Is Nothing Then Set localFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FSO = localFSO
End Function

Public Function WaitForFileToExist(ByVal theFileName As String) As Boolean
    Dim timeElapsed As Single
    Dim startTime As Single
    startTime = Timer
    
    Do
        If FSO.FileExists(theFileName) Then
            WaitForFileToExist = True
            Exit Do
        End If

        DoEvents
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        
        timeElapsed = Timer - startTime
    Loop Until timeElapsed > timeoutSeconds
End Function
```